# FFmpeg command to convert a video for PlayStation 4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, playstation, ps4

I have a video (`input.mp4`) that I would like to play video on my PS4. Using `ffmpeg`, how do I convert that video to be played on the PS4 using a thumbdrive?

I searched and tried several methods, but nothing turned out to be useful.

**Steps followed**

`ffmpeg -i NVP.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -profile:v high -level 4.2 -vf format=yuv420p output.mkv` (does not work)

I created a directory called "Videos" and copied the file (`output.mkv`) in there.

My thumb drive is a 4GB drive formatted as FAT32

[image]

My machine is using macOS Mojave (10.14.6).

From [PlayStation's resources](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/music/mp_format_m.html), the format has to be

- MKV
- Video: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level 4.2
- Audio: MP3, AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital)

Comment: Just for some more information, [here is an official list](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/music/mp_format_m.html) of the video/audio/container formats supported by the PS4 and PS4  Pro.

Comment: The PS4 should be able to play MP4 files, but the file you're talking about may have characteristics (e.g. codecs) that make it unplayable on a PS4. What happens when you try to play it? What happens when you try to play your conversion attempts?

Comment: I did a conversion like this [https://superuser.com/questions/563997/how-can-i-set-a-h-264-profile-level-with-ffmpeg] (1st answer)
 and when I copied the file to a thumb drive & when I tried to view in "Media Player" the file never showed up.

Comment: ' ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level:v 4.0 -c:a copy output.mp4'

Comment: Please show the full command line output from that command you ran. It helps if you ask the question "why does this video not play" rather than asking what hypothetically works in general.

Comment: I have updated the question @slhck | Thank you.

Comment: As I wrote before, could you please show the full command line output from the ffmpeg command? It's easier to troubleshoot then.